# How to get a list of <a> href found in an element?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Given an html like this:

```
<tr>
    <th style="padding-right:1em">Location</th>
    <td>
        <span class="location">Lower reaches of the <a href="/wiki/Geum_River" title="Geum River">Geum River</a>, <a href="/wiki/Korea" title="Korea">Korea</a></span>
    </td>
</tr>
```

How do I get `Geum_River` and `Korea`?

This is what I am doing at the moment:

```
countryLinks = doSelect("Location").siblings('td').find('a').attr('href');
function doSelect(text) {
  return $wikiDOM.find(".infobox th").filter(function() {
    return $(this).text() === text;
  });
}

function countryList() {
  let pattern = new RegExp('\/wiki\/');
  string = countryLinks;
  countryListLinks = string.replace(pattern, '');
  console.log(countryListLinks);
}

if (doSelect('Location').length > 0 && doSelect('Date').length > 0) {
  countryList();
};
```

I am splitting `/wiki/` from the string and it works but I am only getting the first one `Geum_River` while I would expect all of the `<a>`s `href`.

Comment: what is `doSelect` ??

Comment: @DelightedD0D updated with doSelect function

Comment: cool, but what is `$wikiDOM`?

Comment: @DelightedD0D it's a whole page I am getting via the api. The issue tho is for that list, nothing to do with doSelect or the api and the content. it's a listing problem

Comment: So, you just want to return the title attribute? Do you have a link to the page?

Comment: What is `countryList()` supposed to do ?? You're calling `string = countryLinks;` which is just undefined. Does `countryListLinks = string.replace(pattern, '');` not currently throw an error?

Comment: @ptts no i don't want the title, I want the list of href exactly how they are less the /wiki/

Comment: why did I get a downvote?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were only selecting first `<a>` element `.href`, `.attr()` returns a single value. Also second condition at `if` `&& doSelect('Date').length > 0` is `false` given HTML at Question.

You can use `.map()` and `.get()` to return an array of `<a>` element `.href` values, then pass `countryList` function to `Array.prototype.forEach()` to iterate `.href` values.

The `RegExp` should also be adjusted to replace all characters up to and including "wiki" `'^.+\/wiki\/'`.

```js
function doSelect(text) {
  return $(".infobox th").filter(function() {
    return $(this).text() === text;
  });
}

countryLinks = doSelect("Location").siblings('td')
.find('a').map(function(i, el) {return el.href}).get(); // .attr('href');

// we can pass this function to `.forEach()` or `.map()`
function countryList(string) {
  let pattern = new RegExp('^.+\/wiki\/'); // adjust `RegExp`
  // string = countryLinks;
  countryListLinks = string.replace(pattern, '');
  console.log(countryListLinks);
}

// the second condition is `false` given HTML at Question
if (doSelect('Location').length > 0 /* && doSelect('Date').length > 0 */) {
  countryLinks.forEach(countryList);
};
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="infobox">

<tr>
    <th style="padding-right:1em">Location</th>
    <td>
        <span class="location">Lower reaches of the <a href="/wiki/Geum_River" title="Geum River">Geum River</a>, <a href="/wiki/Korea" title="Korea">Korea</a></span>
    </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Hi thanks, this is promising but I am only getting the second one, Korea when i do `console.log(countryLinks.forEach(countryList));` and the first one is `undefined`

Comment: @rob.m `return` `countryListLinks` from `countryList` function and use `.map()` within `if` statement `console.log(countryLinks.map(countryList));`

Comment: going to try now

Answer (score 0):

Your main issue is when you call `countryLinks = doSelect("Location").siblings('td').find('a').attr('href');` specifically, when you call the last bit `.attr('href');` [which the docs state this of](http://api.jquery.com/attr/)

> Description: Get the value of an attribute for the first element in the set of matched elements.

So basically, you're getting a collection of the links then reducing that collection to just the first element and return *it's* href attribute.

#### Here is how I would do this using [`.map()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.map/) instead:

```js
var $wikiDOM = $('.some-container');

var links = $.map($wikiDOM.find('td a'),function(link, i){
     return (link.href || '').replace(/^.*[\\\/]/, '');
});
console.log(links);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="some-container">
<table>
    <tr>
    <th style="padding-right:1em">Location</th>
    <td>
        <span class="location">Lower reaches of the <a href="/wiki/Geum_River" title="Geum River">Geum River</a>, <a href="/wiki/Korea" title="Korea">Korea</a></span>
    </td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
```

Comment: This will get the "filename" value from each link, that is to say the value after the last `/`, if you dont want that, just change the regex back to what you had `'/wiki/'`

Answer (score 0):

you can use jQuery each() to get all the hrefs in a array and then display then one by one using for loop.
Here is the code:

```
var hrefs = new Array();

jQuery('.location').find('a').each(function() {
    hrefs.push(jQuery(this).attr('href'));
});

function countryList() {
  let pattern = new RegExp('\/wiki\/');
for(var i=0; i < hrefs.length ; i++){
  string = hrefs[i];
  var countryListLinks = string.replace(pattern, '');
  alert(countryListLinks);
}
}

countryList();
```

**Complete Code, should look somthing like this:**

```
function doSelect(text) {
  return $wikiDOM.find(".infobox th").filter(function() {
    return $(this).text() === text;
  });
}

var hrefs = new Array();

jQuery('.location').find('a').each(function() {
    hrefs.push(jQuery(this).attr('href'));
});
function countryList() {
  let pattern = new RegExp('\/wiki\/');
for(var i=0; i < hrefs.length ; i++){
  string = hrefs[i];
  var countryListLinks = string.replace(pattern, '');
  console.log(countryListLinks);
}
}
if (doSelect('Location').length > 0 && doSelect('Date').length > 0) {
  countryList();
};
```

```js
  var hrefs = new Array();

    
    jQuery('.location').find('a').each(function() {
        hrefs.push(jQuery(this).attr('href'));
    });
    
    function countryList() {
      let pattern = new RegExp('\/wiki\/');
    for(var i=0; i < hrefs.length ; i++){
      string = hrefs[i];
      var countryListLinks = string.replace(pattern, '');
      alert(countryListLinks);
    }
    }
    
    countryList();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<tr>
    <th style="padding-right:1em">Location</th>
    <td>
        <span class="location">Lower reaches of the <a href="/wiki/Geum_River" title="Geum River">Geum River</a>, <a href="/wiki/Korea" title="Korea">Korea</a></span>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score -1):

First of all, I'm going to pop an `id` onto your span element so that I can locate it easily in my script.

`<span id="locations"`

Next, I'm going to drop your implementation, and instead, iterate through the child elements of the `span` with `id="locations"`. Next, I'll get the substring of the href of these elements that we want, and push them to an array.

```
var locations = document.getElementById("locations").getElementsByTagName('a');
var rawLocations = [];
for (i in locations) {
    if (locations[i].href) {
        var lastIndex = locations[i].href.lastIndexOf('/') + 1;
        rawLocations.push(locations[i].href.substring(lastIndex));
    }
}
```

Now, `console.log(rawLocations);` gives us what we want:

`(2) ["Geum_River", "Korea"]`

Answer (score -1):

This was not as easy as I thought:-)

But here we go:
    // cache the element, you could do QuerySelectorAll and iterate through the 
    // node list, but let's keep it simple
    var ts = document.querySelector('a');

```
// This is caching the href attribute from the link
var garbage = ts.href;

// here you take the link and run the native string method 
// to find the lastIndexOf, this is great if you suck at regex like myself
var n = garbage.lastIndexOf('/');

Here we extract only the part after lastIndexOf and cache it in "result"
var result = garbage.substring(n + 1);
alert(result);
```

Comment: This doesnt really address the actual issue which was that the OP is only getting one of the two links. The issue has to do with element selection, not string manipulation

Comment: Come on, then just use QuerySelectorAll and loop over it, the problem was resolved with one of 2 links. He should be able to figure out the rest.

Comment: The whole problem is that the OP is reducing the collection by calling `.attr()` which *Gets the value of an attribute for the first element in the set of matched elements.* Their original method of getting the string they want *from the href* was perfectly fine. All you have done is suggest an alternate way to do the *one part of the OP's code that does work*.